# Applescript to add an audio file to keynote and upload the file to youtube

Tags: youtube, applescript, automator, keynote

I am trying to use either automator or applescript to do two things.

1. add an mp3 to an open keynote presentation (to the entire presentation and not a single slide)
2. upload the resulting keynote presentation to youtube.

If I use the add file command, as below it doesn't seem to work, although if i replace slideshow with slide 1, then it adds it to slide 1 only.

Thanks very much.

```
tell application "Keynote"
    tell slideshow 1
        add file slideshow 1 path theFile
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to add a soundtrack to the slideshow, not add a file. Unfortunately I do not see a way to do this with applescript. Normally you do this by hand in the Inspector->Documents->Audio section. I also do not see an applescript command for the Share->Send To->YouTube command either.

It seems you can't do either of the things you want by applescripting keynote. Keynote doesn't have those applescript commands. It doesn't have any keyboard shortcuts for those things either, so it can't be accomplished with GUI scripting. Sorry.

Comment: that really sucks, I could do this very easily on powerpoint with vba macro, I thought something like that would be available for keynote as well when I made the switch. Now I use powerpoint to handle such intensive manual tasks and then edit with keynote. No the best but works, better than adding one file at a time manually