# Add soundtrack to a keynote using applescript

Tags: applescript, keynote

I want to add an mp3 soundtrack to an already open keynote presentation using applescript. The soundtrack should start on the first slide, and loop as long as the presentation is running.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329051/applescript-to-add-an-audio-file-to-keynote-and-upload-the-file-to-youtube) was asked 6-7 years ago, which had more parts to it. Keynote has gone through significant updates since then, and I am only interested in ability to add the soundtrack.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any AppleScript.

- Open up your slideshow
- Select "Document" (Top right corner of the keynote)
- Drop your soundtrack in
- Select "Loop"

[image: ref]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am very well aware of this option. I indeed want to be able to do this through applescript